# Do .NET Assemblies Cache References To Other Assemblies?

Tags: .net, reflection, assemblies, typechecking

This might sound like an odd question (I've, at least, never had reason to think about it until now), but let me explain my situation.

We have a service app that runs on servers on our client's networks.  To update the app, we push a new build of the service's core assembly to our server and issue soft restarts to the service apps, which are really just a shell for the core.  The individual service apps request a byte array of the core assembly and new assembly is executed:

```
Assembly coreAsm = Assembly.Load(coreAsmByteArray);
Type tCoreHelper = GetInterfaceTypeFromAssembly(coreAsm, typeof(ICoreHelper));
_CoreHelper = Activator.CreateInstance(tCoreHelper) as ICoreHelper;

_CoreHelper.Start();
```

Everything needed for service execution has been contained in the core assembly, until recently.

We just made some changes to also allow plugin assemblies to be requested by the service app.  When the service first runs, it requests the core assembly, and the core requests the plugins and loads them the same way the core was (different and correct types assumed).  The assemblies are reloaded and everything is happy.  However, when we issue a soft restart, the core assembly requested, and the core assembly requests the plugins.  The core and plugin assemblies are successfully loaded however, type checks between plugin and core types start failing.

After loading the plugin assembly we peruse the plugin's types looking for worker classes, IWorker, which is a type defined in the core assembly (meaning all plugin assemblies reference the core):

In assembly Core:

```
namespace Core
{
    public interface IWorker { ... }
}
```

In assembly PluginTest:

```
namespace PluginTest
{
    public class PluginA : Core.IWorker { ... }
}
```

All workers previously found on the initial load of the service app are no longer found after a soft restart, because (new)Core.IWorker is no longer assignable from the plugin worker types.  Though the debugger disagrees, and evaluates the call to IsAssignableFrom in the manner I want it to, the CLR is doing something different, causing the check to fail:

```
foreach(var t in pluginAsm.GetTypes())
{
    if(otherChecksPass && typeof(IWorker).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        RegisterPluginType(t);
}
```

I imagine that, when changing the core assembly out from under the plugins, the plugins aren't getting the memo about the new core assembly, and continuing to use a "cached" reference to the old assembly.  But I really don't know how this kind of situation plays out in memory, nor do I have any clue how I would go about fixing such a condition.

Questions? Thoughts?  Thank you all!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "soft restart"?

Comment: It stops its polling, reloads the core/plugins and related data, then resumes polling.  The actual service app itself is not unloaded from memory.  Restarting the service app DOES fix this problem, but is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: Does the service ever unloads the core/plugins/related data? How?

Comment: all data is nulled out and re-requested.  Loaded plugin data is nulled out and refreshed.  But as far as I know there isn't a way to unload an assembly from the app domain, so all assemblies are rerequested and their byte data passed to Assembly.Load()

Comment: It is no doubt a consequence of using Assembly.Load(byte[]).  Calling it again produces a *new* assembly whose types have a different identity.

Comment: Assembly loading belongs to an `AppDomain`, not to an individual assembly. So you'll either need to load your core into a new `AppDomain` and subsequently unload it when you want to "soft restart" or you can resort to hacky interop to unload the plugin DLLs (highly unrecommended).

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer that was the issue.  We ended up creating an assembly loader class that loads the assemblies with workers into a separate app domain.  Then on restart, unload and reload the app domain.  Things are working ver well now.

Comment: @WesP Excellent. Good to hear it worked out.